# How to create DLL for C# application using MSBuild?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am new to MSBuild and am trying to create a DLL using C# console application.

I am not a .net programmer and not using Visual Studio

```
using System;
namespace FunctionEx {
    public class Functions {

        public void sum()
        {
            int a = 2;
            int b = 3;
            int c = a + b;
            Console.WriteLine("Sum is " + c);
        }
    }
}
```

My MSBuild file looks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="14.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <AssemblyName>FunctionsExample</AssemblyName>
    <OutputPath>Bin\</OutputPath>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Functions.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" />
    <Csc Sources="@(Compile)" OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).exe" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Clean">
      <Delete Files="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="ReBuild" DependsOnTargets="Clean;Build" />
      
</Project>
```

MSBuild produces the following error which is understandable.

Error Message

```
CSC : error CS5001: Program 'e:\Exercises\CSharp\FunctionEx\Bin\FunctionsExample.dll' does not contain a
static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [E:\Exercises\CSharp\FunctionEx\Functions.csproj]
```

However, as I am trying to create a DLL my .cs file will not have `Main method` in it

Answer (score 0):

I added property `TargetType="Library"` in addition to `<OutputType>Library</OutputType>` and I was able to create the DLL

```
<Csc Sources="@(Compile)" OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll"  TargetType="library" />
```